# Is it correct to say I am deploying components via Kubernetes?

Tags: spring, docker, jenkins, kubernetes, terminology

I have some questions about terminology that I should use. I have searched up the components that I am using, but I am still not sure. Can you please check if these are right way to describe each component? If not, can you please revise it?

1. I develop microservices using Spring Framework (Spring boot).
2. I deploy components on cloud via Kubernetes and Docker. (I understand Docker is used for containerizing and Kubernetes is for orchestrating multiple containers. Is it right to say "I deploy on Kubernetes or via Kubernetes"?)
3. CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins and Azure DevOps. (Project uses Azure DevOps for triggering CI/CD in Jenkins)

Please note that this project was already there when I joined the team, and I am new to all of these concepts. I understand what they do briefly and I know what each terminology means on entry level, but I just want to make sure if I am saying these in right ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I develop microservices using Spring Framework (Spring boot).

To understand in the most basic form - Microservices is an architectural pattern for developing applications, so there can be many ways to implement this pattern (which is nothing but developing applications) and Spring Boot is one of them. More precisely you should say "I develop microservices using Spring Boot"

> I deploy components on cloud via Kubernetes and Docker. (I understand
> Docker is used for containerizing and Kubernetes is for orchestrating
> multiple containers. Is it right to say "I deploy on Kubernetes or via
> Kubernetes"?)

Precisely speaking you are not correct here - you understand the purpose of Docker and Kubernetes but putting it wrongly w.r.t. application and its deployment.

Do read [this](http://Kubernetes%20is%20an%20open-source%20system%20for%20automating%20deployment,%20scaling,%20and%20management%20of%20containerized%20applications.), where it is clearly mentioned that K8s doesn't build or deploy code. When the official documentation is clearly saying that K8s doesn't deploy code, then how you can say that I deploy via K8s?

I would say you shouldn't put it using either of the statement you mentioned, rather you should say - "My application runs (or is deployed) in Cloud on a Kubernetes cluster (or GKE or EKS or AKS)".

> CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins and Azure DevOps. (Project uses Azure
> DevOps for triggering CI/CD in Jenkins)

Looks fine to me.

---

Please note that in general you can say anything as long as the other person is able to understand, so in general all your statements might sell well. But I guess you were looking for "precise" statements, and I gave you my thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you deploy services, not components, but your team might have its own terminology.

You do deploy on Kubernetes.

Docker is used to create and manage containers and container images. Kubernetes does not use Docker but can use images created via Docker to deploy containers in Pods (via the OCI format)

The rest seems right to me :)

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes an app as a unit is called Service. It has components reachable under it, for example: deployment, pod, etc. This set of components could be for microservice or service, but terminology just a service.

You can list all services using `kubectl get services`

The Docker is related here only because pod has a container or sometimes few of them. So Kubernetes supports Docker and its images. It's most popular container runtime in 2021, but not the only one for Kubernetes.

To combine everything, the right sentence to me would be:

I deploy a service on Kubernetes

I deploy a service on Amazon EKS

I deploy a service on Azure Kubernetes

etc.

Adding "cloud" doesn't add so much value as Kubernetes platform is same regardless of cloud provider chosen. Of course, there are some differences in cloud, but not in Kubernetes core.

Docker doesn't fit here and usually discussed when going into details, especially about images, building them, etc.

Also off topic, but even pod is more used than container, because in Kubernetes you access the pod (while in Docker Compose, you access the container). Of course, you can access Docker container if there are multiple of them setup in a pod and container engine is Docker in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Guys here are right but I would like to add that when speaking of **Kubernetes components** you usually think of [Control Plane Components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#control-plane-components) or [Node Components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#node-components) and when speaking of smaller units the [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) comes to mind first. Note that a Kubernetes service is an abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service. So addressing your main question:

> Is it correct to say I am deploying components via Kubernetes?

It would be better to say that you are deploying a service/application (running) on Kubernetes (on AKS/AWS/GCP/etc).